# Как вывести живые пайплайны в jenkins в отдельное окно?

Tags: jenkins

Не так давно начал изучать дженкинс, возник вопрос. В очереди показывается история запущенных пайплайнов, дело в том, что пайплайн 1 может длиться часа 3, а запущенные после него несколько минут, и все еще живой пайплайн прячется внизу очереди. Есть ли плагин или другой способ поддерживать не закрытые пайплайны наверху, или вывести их отдельно?

Comment: Не надо добавлять в вопрос "всем привет" и прочую лирику. Хоть это и вежливо, но правилами не приветствуются, потом кто-нибудь выпилит всё-равно )

Comment: Принял, спасибо